# Keep a Dictionary<Type, MyClass<T>> where elements are referenceable by type

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have an abstract class called EntityTypeTransform with a single abstract method designed to hold a Func delegate that converts an IDataRecord into an instance of T.

```
public abstract class EntityTypeTransform<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
{
    public abstract Func<IDataRecord, TEntityType> GetDataTransform();
}
```

An implementation of that class might look like (does look like) this:

```
public class TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform : EntityTypeTransform<TaskParameter>
{
    public override Func<IDataRecord, TaskParameter> GetDataTransform()
    {
        return dataRecord => new TaskParameter()
        {
            TaskId = (int)dataRecord["task_id"],
            Name = (string)dataRecord["p_name"],
            Value = (string)dataRecord["p_value"]
        };
    }
}
```

Now I want to keep an instance of each of these classes in a generic Dictionary, something like:

```
Dictionary<Type, EntityTypeTransform<T>>
```

But this doesn't work because (for example) an instance of EntityTypeTransform Of Task is not the same as an instance of EntityTypeTransform Of TaskParameter.

Can anyone help me out?

Edit: I should add that the Type key = typeof(T)

Comment: The generic dictionary should be defined under the same class under which the rest of the generic stuff are defined. If you post your entire class (minus uninteresting methods and fields), perhaps I will see the problem.

Comment: You simply need to change the transform classes so that they return `object` instead. That's not going to be worse that what you already have: even if you could put them into the dictionary as-is, the indirection through it means that the type of each transform's result cannot be known statically so you have to treat it as `object` anyway.

Comment: Do you need multiple instances of this dictionary or a single cache per application?

Comment: I only need a single cache per application. In fact I prefer a single cache.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to use a dictionary at all! You can use the fact that `GenericClass<T>` is actually a different type for each T, so it can have its own static fields (i.e. `GenericClass<Foo>.SomeField` is not shared with `GenericClass<Bar>.SomeField`)

For instance you can implement your cache like this:

```
static class TransformCache<TEntityType>
{
    public static EntityTypeTransform<TEntityType> Transform { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
TransformCache<TaskParameter>.Transform = new TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't specify a strong-typed collection that would hold different generic types. Here's the approach I've used in a similar problem, modified to match your requirement:

```
class TransformCollection
{
   private Hashtable cache = new Hashtable();

   public void Add<T>(EntityTypeTransform<T> transform) where T : class
   {
      this.cache[typeof(T)] = itemToCache;
   }

   public bool Exists<T>() where T : class
   {
      return this.cache.ContainsKey(typeof(T));
   }

   public EntityTypeTransform<T> Get<T>() where T : class
   {
      if (!this.Exists<T>())
         throw new ArgumentException("No cached transform of type: " + typeof(T).Name);
      return this.cache[typeof(T)] as EntityTypeTransform<T>;
   }
}
```

This gives you type-safe cache for your generic type (though type-safety is enforced by the class's logic, not C#). You can use it as follows:

```
var collection = new TransformCollection();
collection.Add(SomeMethodToGetTransform<Task>());
//...
if (collection.Exists<Task>())
{
   var transform = collection.Get<Task>();
   //...
}
```

Comment: that last `ExpressionComparer<T>;` is that just a old class you forgot to rename from a copy and paste?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an interface that is non-generic and then implement that interface explicitly inside that abstract class, It's pretty common in the .Net library itself:

```
public interface IEntityTypeTransform
{
    Func<IDataRecord, object> GetDataTransform();
}

public abstract class EntityTypeTransform<TEntityType> : IEntityTypeTransform
    where TEntityType : class
{
    public virtual Func<IDataRecord, TEntityType> GetDataTransform()
    {
        return this.GetDataTransformImpl();
    }

    public abstract Func<IDataRecord, TEntityType> GetDataTransformImpl();

    Func<IDataRecord, object> IEntityTypeTransform.GetDataTransform()
    {
        return this.GetDataTransform();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the intention is then to put implementations of the abstract class into a Dictionary<Type, IEntityTypeTransform> ?

Comment: @StuartMeeks Exactly.

Comment: Why did you add the abstract method?

Comment: I usually do this to keep it consistent (each generic implementation drives from the abstract class) and also for convenience - you don't have to implement the interface in each implementation and you only have to override `GetDataTransformImpl`.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a non-generic base class, e.g.

```
public abstract class EntityTypeTransformBase
{
    public abstract Func<IDataRecord, object> GetDataTransform();
}

public abstract class EntityTypeTransform<TEntityType> : EntityTypeTransformBase where TEntityType : class
{
    public abstract Func<IDataRecord, TEntityType> GetDataTransformImpl();

    public override Func<IDataRecord, object> GetDataTransform()
    {
        return GetDataTransformImpl();
    }
}

public class TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform : EntityTypeTransform<TaskParameter>
{
    public override Func<IDataRecord, TaskParameter> GetDataTransformImpl()
    {
        return dataRecord => new TaskParameter()
        {
            TaskId = (int)dataRecord["task_id"],
            Name = (string)dataRecord["p_name"],
            Value = (string)dataRecord["p_value"]
        };
    }
}
```

Now you can create your dictionary:

```
var d = new Dictionary<Type, EntityTypeTransformBase>();
d.Add(typeof(TaskParameter), new TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`KeyedByTypeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404549.aspx) to get type-safety and you can define an interface with a covariant type parameter to make sure that only objects of type `EntityTypeTransform<T>` can be added to the dictionary:

```
public interface IEntityTypeTransform<out TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
{
    TEntityType Transform(IDataRecord dataRecord);
}

public abstract class EntityTypeTransform<TEntityType> : IEntityTypeTransform<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
{
    public abstract TEntityType Transform(IDataRecord dataRecord);
}

public class TaskParameter
{
    public int TaskId;
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
}

public class TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform : EntityTypeTransform<TaskParameter>
{
    public override TaskParameter Transform(IDataRecord dataRecord)
    {
        return new TaskParameter()
        {
            TaskId = (int)dataRecord["task_id"],
            Name = (string)dataRecord["p_name"],
            Value = (string)dataRecord["p_value"]
        };
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public KeyedByTypeCollection<IEntityTypeTransform<object>> TransformDictionary = new KeyedByTypeCollection<IEntityTypeTransform<object>>()
    {
        new TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform(),
        // More transforms here
    };
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(IDataRecord dataRecord)
{
    TaskParameter taskParameter = TransformDictionary.Find<TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform>().Transform(dataRecord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a non generic interface to your transformers:

```
public interface IEntityTypeTransform
{
    Func<IDataRecord, object> GetDataTransform();
}
public abstract class EntityTypeTransform<T> : IEntityTypeTransform
{
    public abstract Func<IDataRecord, object> GetDataTransform();
}
public class TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform : EntityTypeTransform<TaskParameter>
{
    public override Func<IDataRecord, object> GetDataTransform()
    {
        return dataRecord => new TaskParameter()
        {
            TaskId = (int)dataRecord["task id"],
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can encapsulate your dictionary for ensure that datatypes will always match. Never allow to add a IEntityTypeTransform of a bad type :

```
public class TransformDistributor
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IEntityTypeTransform> _transforms = new Dictionary<Type, IEntityTypeTransform>();
    public void Add<T>(EntityTypeTransform<T> type)
    {
        this._transforms.Add(typeof(T), type);
    }
    public T Transform<T>(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var transform = this._transforms[typeof(T)].GetDataTransform()(record);
        if (transform is T)
        {
            return (T)transform;
        }
        else
        {
            // theorically can't happen
            throw new InvalidOperationException("transformer doesn't return instance of type " + transform.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage are that at compile time, your are sure that nobody can insert a bad transformer, even if your are not using generics.

Usage :

```
var transforms = new TransformDistributor();
transforms.Add<TaskParameter>(new TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform());

var taskParameter = transforms.Transform<TaskParameter>(new DataRecord());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to understand what you exactly want I hope this is exactly what you are looking for!

You shall set in TaskParameter class the correct parameters: TaskId, Name, Value

```
public abstract class EntityTypeTransform<TEntityType> where TEntityType : class
{
  public abstract Func<IDataRecord, TEntityType> GetDataTransform();
}

public class TaskParameterEntityTypeTransform : EntityTypeTransform<TaskParameter>
{
  public override Func<IDataRecord, TaskParameter> GetDataTransform()
  {
    return x => new TaskParameter { X = x.FieldCount };
  }
}

public class TaskParameter
{
  public int X { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<Type, EntityTypeTransform<TaskParameter>> imADict;
```

Comment: Not quite. This only lets me store instances of EntityTypeTransform<TaskParameter>. I also have EntityTypeTransform<Task> that I want to store in the same "collection".